# ios cell highlight color clipstobounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

Upon changing the highlight color of the cell when selected, the box drawn around the top and bottom of the table no longer clips within the table's borders.

I have tried clipsToBounds with both tableView and the cells, but with no luck.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

image of the problem >

[image]

Comment: how did you change the highlight color of cell?

Comment: May be it can be fixed by using layer's setMasksToBounds property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a idea how to make the effect you need work, may not be the best way but you can have a try.

first check if the cell is the last cell; if so:

```
UIBezierPath *lastCellMask;
lastCellMask = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];

CAShapeLayer *cellMaskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
cellMaskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
cellMaskLayer.path = lastCellMask.CGPath;
cell.layer.mask = cellMaskLayer;
```

and do the reverse for the first cell

This works for me, check if this can help u

Comment: Hey, do u know which header I need to include? it's giving me 2 Mach-O linker errors. So far I only have QuartzCore included

Comment: Thanks!_______________(needs underscores because stackoverflow hates me)

Comment: Does it work? I think you only need #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> for this

Comment: lol yes after importing QuartzCore to the build target. Silly me

Answer (score 0):

looking at the image, try

```
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `grouped` style for your table view. The grouped table view doesn't have the margins that you are seeing in the UI, and using `clipToBounds` won't help because the cells bounds are exactly the ones you are seeing when you are selecting the cell. What you could do is use the `cornerRadius` layer property for your cell (only the first and last cell in the section) in order to round the corners and create the desired result.